# Цикл внутри рекурсивной функции не итерируется до конца Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Решаю задачу "Millipede of words". В функцию подается список слов. Функция должна вернуть True, если все слова списка можно соединить, чтобы последняя буква предыдущего слова была такой же, как и первая буква следующего слова. В обратном случае - False.
Написал такой код:

```
def solution(arr):
    def recurtion(arr, letter):
        if len(arr) == 1:
            if arr[0][0] == letter:
                return True

        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if arr[i][0] == letter:
                return recurtion(arr[0:i] + arr[i+1:], arr[i][-1])

    for j in range(len(arr)):
        if recurtion(arr[0:j] + arr[j+1:], arr[j][-1]):
            return True
    return False
```

Идея в том, чтобы взять каждое отдельное слово из списка за первое, передать в рекурсивную функцию оставшийся список и последнюю букву первого слова, там перебираем все слова, если есть подходящее, то передаем в функцию его последнюю букву и оставшийся список и т.д. Если осталось одно слово и буквы совпадают, то возвращаем True, в обратном случае False.
Но вот например на таком списке тест не проходит:

```
['tablet', 'endorse', 'transport', 'elephant', 'evaluate', 'embrace', 'empire']
```

Проблема в том, что цикл for в recurtion() не итерируется до конца, если какое либо слово подошло, то вызывается рекурсивная функция и по тем словам, которые идут дальше for почему-то больше не итерируется.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Если есть какие-либо замечания, напишите тоже, пожалуйста.

Comment: а что будет, если arr[0][0] не равно letter или arr[i][0] не равно letter? PS: Кто вас научили создавать функции внутри функций?

Comment: если arr[0][0] не равно letter: recursion() вернет None, solution() вернет False
Про функцию внутри функции понимаю, что плохо, но автопроверщик на сайте, где я задачи решаю должен получить одну функцию solution(), а как сделать без вложенной функции я не придумал.

Comment: Там в чем проблема в этом примере:
если слово 'elephant' в списке поставить в конец, то все получится, вернется True.
Когда цикл проходит слово 'endorse', остаток отправляет в рекурсию.
Потом идут по очереди слова 'tablet' и 'transport', они тоже подходят, но потом 'elephant' это тупик, но мы уже вызвали рекурсию на оставшийся после 'elephant' список, а по остальным словам цикл почему-то уже не идет. Я не понимаю почему

Comment: тут нужно использовать другой подход - просто подсчитать количество первых и последних букв и там уже смотреть, можно ли из них построить цепочку (подсказка - каждой буквы должно быть четное количество, но две могут быть непарными, это будут первое и последнее слово в цепочке).

Comment: а рекурсия у вас похоже просто проверяет одинаковые ли крайние буквы у соседних слов.

Comment: Да, я тоже так решал сначала, но там в тестах вот такие вещи есть например ['on', 'no', 'dog', 'god]. Формально четное количество, а ряд не получится. Поэтому я в рекурсию и залез. А теперь уже интересно, почему прерывается цикл.

Comment: Да, рекурсия проверяет крайние буквы, если не совпадают, просто прерывается

Comment: ну так вам нужно же проверить можно ли СОСТАВИТЬ ряд, а не стоят ли слова в нужном порядке. А проверить одинаковость крайних букв у соседних слов можно и без рекурсии

Comment: Пускай, задачу можно и по-другому решить. Мне теперь интересно почему не итерируется полностью цикл в рекурсивно вызываемой функции

Comment: ну вот же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474688/%d0%a6%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-python?noredirect=1#comment2640176_1474688

Comment: Вот мы идем циклом for по списку: 'elephant', 'evaluate', 'embrace', 'empire'
Последняя буква предыдущего слова у нас е. Вызывается рекурсивно функция со списком 'evaluate', 'embrace', 'empire', т.к. 'elephant' соответствует условию, но она дальше прерывается, потому что дальше условие уже не соблюдается. Но вот изначальный for уже не итерируется, то есть по 'evaluate', 'embrace', 'empire' он уже не пойдет. Почему?

Comment: @NoFate Он идёт по этим словам, но elephant всё портит. Тут получается, что в рекурсии надо выпрыгнуть назад и пропустить его.

Comment: А с чего бы циклу for в `recurtion()` «продолжать» итерации, если из него делается безусловный return? А вот цикл for в `sollution()` вполне себе «продолжает».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше решение зависит от порядка слов в списке:

> ```
> ['ab', 'bb', 'bс'] -> True
> ['ab', 'bс', 'bb'] -> False
> ```

Ошибка в этом фрагменте:

```
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i][0] == letter:
            return recurtion(arr[0:i] + arr[i+1:], arr[i][-1])
```

Цикл проверяет только первое подходящее слово. Такие слова в примере - `bb` и `bc`. Отличается только порядок. Если первое `bb`, всё хорошо. Если - `bc`, рекурсивный вызов заканчивается неуспехом, но следующее слово не будет проверено.

Исправление. В случае неуспеха продолжается поиск среди оставшихся слов:

```
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i][0] == letter:
            if recurtion(arr[0:i] + arr[i+1:], arr[i][-1]):
                return True
```

Оставшиеся недочёты, не ошибки.

1. `recurtion` возвращает `True` или `None` (то есть он ничего не возвращает, но Питон так устроен, что тогда возвращаемым значением становится `пусто`). `return False` в конце `recurtion` исправляет ситуацию.
2. `if len(arr) == 1:` - слишком рано срабатывает. Можно сделать код проще, если прекращать рекурсию, когда массив пуст:

```
    def recurtion(arr, letter):
        if not arr: # список пуст
            return True

        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if arr[i][0] == letter:
                if recurtion(arr[0:i] + arr[i+1:], arr[i][-1]):
                    return True

        return False
```

3. Поиск по словам есть в `solution` и в `recurtion`. Дублирование - не хорошо. Хотя циклы отличаются, их можно объединить с помощью `str.startswith`:

```
def solution(arr):

    def recurtion(arr, prefix):
        if not arr: # список пуст
            return True

        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if arr[i].startswith(prefix):
                if recurtion(arr[0:i] + arr[i+1:], arr[i][-1]):
                    return True

        return False

    return recurtion(arr, '')
```

4. `recurtion` -> `recursion`.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за подробное объяснение и предложения! Теперь все понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Задача не нова, на английском stackoverflow быстрее всего с данным массивом отработал [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53485052/longest-word-chain-from-a-list-of-words/53485347#53485347).

```python
def solution(arr):
    return len(max(list(chains(arr)), key=len)) == len(arr)

def chains(words, previous_word_index=None):
    yield []
    if previous_word_index is not None:
        previous_letter = words[previous_word_index][-1]
        words = words[:previous_word_index] + words[previous_word_index + 1:]
    for i, each_word in enumerate( words ):
        if previous_word_index is None or each_word.startswith(previous_letter):
            for tail in chains(words, previous_word_index=i):
                yield [each_word] + tail
```

###### Вывод:

```console
Wall time: 998 µs

True
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Но меня не столько решение задачи интересует, я не понимаю, почему прерывается итерация внутри рекурсивной функции. Спасибо!